# set Woocommerce brand image as product placeholder image

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to show woocommerce brand image as default product image if there is no image assigned to the product. for example, Suppose a product of assigned with amazon store don't have an image by default it will show amazon logo as the featured product image. 
Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the filter woocommerce_placeholder_img_src.

```
// run the function on only product pages and category pages
add_action('init', 'dwd_run_brands_on_product_and_categories_only');
function dwd_run_brands_on_product_and_categories_only() {
    if ( (!is_admin()) && (is_product() || is_product_category())) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src','dwd_replace_placeholder_image_with_brand');
    }
}

// Add brand image to products that have no image
function dwd_replace_placeholder_image_with_brand() {
    global $product;

    $productImage = wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() );
    if (empty($productImage) && (is_product_category() || is_product())) {
        $productBrands = wp_get_object_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pwb-brand' );

        foreach( $productBrands as $brand ) {
            $brandLogo = get_term_meta( $brand->term_id, 'pwb_brand_image', true );
            $brandLogo = wp_get_attachment_url( $brandLogo );
            return $brandLogo;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this code works with the Perfect Brands for WooCommerce plugin. So, if you use another brand plugin, you will need to replace 'pwb-brand' and 'pwb_brand_image' with the correct term and meta_key.

This can be added to your theme's function.php, or create a plugin as outlined here: https://www.dwdonline.com/uncategorized/show-product-brand-image-for-products-with-no-image-in-woocommerce.html

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite WooCommerce default **placeholder.png** image with this hook **woocommerce_placeholder_img_src**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src','your_func_name');
function your_func_name(){
return 'Brand Image URL':
}
```